# C++ header-only library avoid "using namespace" pollution

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I have a header-only C++ library with several namespaces.

For example one header file may contain

```
//header1.h
namespace library{
namespace componentA{
   template<typename T>
   class Someclass{};
}
}
```

And another one

```
//header2.h
namespace library{
namespace componentB{
   template<typename T>
   class SomeOtherClass{
       void Foo(const componentA::Someclass<T>& reference);
       void Bar(const componentA::Someclass<T>& reference);
   };
}
}
```

Now while this works, having a header-only library it becomes tedious to write the namespace again and again, especially when you are having multiple classes and nested namespaces involved.

So I did this:

```
//new header2.h
namespace library{
namespace componentB{

   using namespace componentA;

   template<typename T>
   class SomeOtherClass{
       void Foo(const Someclass<T>& reference);
       void Bar(const Someclass<T>& reference);
       void FooBar(const Someclass<T>& reference);
       void FooWithBar(const Someclass<T>& reference);
   };
}
}
```

While this is certainly more convenient to type, it has the problem that now a client of the library can also use `Someclass<T>` by using the `componentB` namespace like this, which leads to an ambiguous interface and ultimately to inconsistent code.
For example a client now could use 
`componentB::Someclass<T>` even though it is originally defined in `componentA`

Is there a way to get the shorthand only available "privately"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured Out the solution myself after a while of thinking. Unfortunately this is not straightforward.

```
//header1.h
namespace lib_noexport{

namespace library{
namespace componentA{
   template<typename T>
   class Someclass{};
}
}
}
}

using namespace lib_noexport;
```

And then

```
//header2.h
namespace lib_noexport{

using library::componentA::Someclass;

namespace library{

    namespace componentB{

       template<typename T>
       class SomeOtherClass{
           void Foo(const Someclass<T>& reference){}
       };
    }
}

}
using namespace lib_noexport;
```

Now this yields the following:

```
library::componentB::SomeOtherClass<int> a; //works as expected
Someclass<int> b; //error
library::componentB::Someclass<int> c; //error
library::componentA::Someclass<int> b; //works
```

Still, the user could be stupid enough to use the undocumented lib_noexport:: but then i cannot help her any more..

Comment: Do you need the `inner` namespace?

Answer (score 6):

```
namespace library {
  namespace componentAImpl{
    using ::library::componentB;
    // ...
    inline namespace exports{
      struct foo{};
    }
  }
  namespace componentA{
    using namespace library::componentAImpl::exports;
  }
}
```

users can access `componentAImpl`, but should not.

Meanwhile, a clean set of symbols are exposed in `library::componentA`.

Comment: Nice. I think this is the correct solution /cc @mightyuhu

Comment: @andy I might use a different `library` namespace, and start names with `details_` to avoid tempting code-completors.  And I am uncertain about how the ADL will work in some cases.  So you'd have to deploy it and see if it has rough spots (I haven't used the above pattern in my code before).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is no. If typing/reading `componentA::` before type names from the `componentA` namespace is too much of a problem (honestly, that would be my preference), then you could use short namespace aliases:

```
namespace library { namespace componentB
{
// ...
namespace ca = componentA;
// ...
void foo(ca::SomeClass<T>);
// ...
} }
```

In any case, I discourage using directives in header files: they lead to name clashes and maintenance issues.

Comment: yes, this would be a possibility to avoid typing the whole name, however 
a client could still access library::componentB::ca::Someclass<T> then...

Comment: @mightyuhu: Yes. This is unavoidable I'm afraid. AFAIK C++'s system based on translation units and include files does not offer better alternatives.

Comment: if you are interested see my answer, maybe i've overseen something

Answer (score 1):

Well, C++ 11? [Using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) introduces a member of another namespace into current namespace or block scope.

```
namespace library{

    namespace componentB{

       using componentA::SomeOtherClass;

       template<typename T>
       SomeOtherClass{
           void Foo(const Someclass<T>& reference);
           void Bar(const Someclass<T>& reference);
           void FooBar(const Someclass<T>& reference);
           void FooWithBar(const Someclass<T>& reference);
       };
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't change the fact that clients can write `componentB::SomeOtherClass` even though `SomeOtherClass` lives in namespace `componentA`.

Comment: Andy Prowl, of course but that would be the other scope?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean

Comment: I would make an additional block scope to prevent that.

Comment: Wait... the additional scope maybe not a solution for the header library. But anyway to me using declaration is cleaner but some malicious user may try to violate the sanity of course.

Comment: That is my "design" problem.

Comment: @Andy, only assuming the namespace componentB first you can then try to do such trick. To me it is not really a problem but looks more like intentional way to violate.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what you mean, but the OP does not want the name `SomeOtherClass` to be injected inside the `componentB` namespace. He also doesn't want to type `componentA::` before `SomeOtherClass` in the header file. AFAIK there is no way to achieve this. To me, this is not really a huge problem: I'd just type `componentA::` or use namespace aliases. I'm against `using` directives and `using` declarations in header files.